# Dlmwrite doesn't give any output to .xls

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab file that reads a text file getting values for `r`, `c` and `Beta`. Using those 3 columns I want to combine this with a file in Matlab with airfoil coordinates which I eventually split up in slices (I want around 30 pieces) of X and Y coordinates.

The problem I'm facing is that the `dlmwrite` doesn't give any output files. The file did work before, but now I don't see any xls file appearing. I have looked at the dlmwrite specifically, but I can't find my mistake.

`n` is the number of slices I want to create, which is equal to the number of lines in the text file which contains `r`, `c` and `Beta`. The `Z = ones(81,1)` is the number of airfoil coordinates (`X` and `Y` together counts as 1)

```
clear all
close all
clc

%Create and output propeller geometry text files for solidworks
Propeller_Geometry = 'lllllaatsten.txt';
Airfoil_Geometry = 'as5048.txt'; %airfoil x_c, z_c

[r, c, beta] = textread(Propeller_Geometry) % (m, m, deg)
[x_c, z_c] = textread(Airfoil_Geometry); %(-, -)

c = c * 1000;           % Chord Length (mm)
r = r * 1000;           % Radius Length (mm)
beta = beta * pi / 180; % Angle from rotational velocity vector to lower blade edge (rad) 
n = 50;                 % Number of slices
hold on
plot(x_c, z_c, '-b')
axis([0 1 -0.5 0.5])
xlabel('Unit Chord ( x/c)', 'fontsize', 14)
ylabel('Unit Height (z/c)', 'fontsize', 14)
title('TA22 Airfoil Geometry', 'fontsize', 14)

%Create dimensional slices
for i=1:n+1
    x = x_c * c(i);                            % Dimensional Chord (mm)
    y = z_c * c(i);                            % Dimensional Height (mm)
    X = x * cos(-beta(i)) - y * sin(-beta(i)); % Rotated x-coordinate
    Y = y * cos(-beta(i)) + x * sin(-beta(i)); % Rotated y-coordinate
    Z = ones(81,1) * r(i);
    P = horzcat(-X, Y, Z);

    %dlmwrite(['Slice_' int2str(i)'.xls'], P, 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', 8)
    %dlmwrite(['stuk_' int2str(i) '.txt'], P, 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', 8)
    dlmwrite (['stuk_' int2str(i) '.xls'], P, '-append', 'delimiter', '\t', 'newline', 'pc')
    plot3(Z, -X, Y);                           %cm
    axis([0 50 -30 0 -7 1])
    xlabel('Radius (mm)', 'fontsize', 18)
    ylabel('Chord (mm)', 'fontsize', 18)
    zlabel('Height (cm)', 'fontsize', 18)
    title('Propeller geometry', 'fontsize', 18)
    grid
end
```

Comment: And no error messages? `dlmwrite` doesn't create `.xls` format files, though. You can certainly create a file with that extension but it won't be in the right format (for that use `xlswrite`).

Comment: No no error messages. That's the weird thing. What I did in the past write is as .txt and open it with excel (though i thought i have been able to write it directly as .xls). Using .txt gives me the same result: nothing. If I use xlswrite, I just have to replace the dlmwrite and leave all the rest? Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: It doesn't take the same options as `dlmwrite` but should be similar - best doublecheck the help file.  Your result is a bit mysterious, though - if you just run the examples in the help for `dlmwrite` do those files appear? (could of course be a version issue or something).

Comment: I'm guessing it is writing in a location that you don't expect.  Maybe try putting the complete path in the file name.

Comment: M= [ 1 2 3 4 ; 4 5 6 7; 7 8 9 0];

dlmwrite('myfile.txt', M, 'delimiter', '\t', ...
         'precision', 6)
type myfile.txt

Is what I tried. If i search on my pc for myfile.txt i don't find a thing, so it's not my first main code which is the proplem, more a problem with the external writing then? Maybe I'll uninstall Matlab and try again, or would that not work?